# How to arrange objects and overlap in sprite kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have an `SKEmitterNode` that I want behind a `SKSpriteNode` but the `SKEmitterNode`keep's going in front of it regardless of how I recode it. I tried making the `SKSpriteNode` a child of it but still had the same problem.

Below is the code:

```
    _player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"shsks.png"] size:CGSizeMake(40,40)];

    _player.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);

    SKEmitterNode *trail = [SKEmitterNode orb_emitterNamed:@"Trail"];
    trail.targetNode = self;

    [_player addChild:trail];
    [self addChild:_player];
```

Can anyone help me out with how I can arrange the code so that the trail is behind the player? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zPosition` to change what order things are drawn in.

I believe that the lower the `zPosition` the further back a node will be drawn.

So set your player to 1 and you emitter to -1.

That should put the player above the emitter.

Comment: Worked perfectly, this means a TON to me. Thanks so much @Fogmeister